# CASE (IF ELSE )

Tags: sql, oracle

if else statement in oracle with condition

```
 SELECT (CASE
               WHEN b.status IN ('AC', 'AB')
                  THEN a.coulmn_id = c.coulmn_id 
               WHEN b.status IN ('GC')
                  THEN a.coulmn_id = 241
            END
           ) status
      FROM table_1 a,
           table_2 b,
           table_3 c
```

Comment: Why would you want a Cartesian product of all the tables?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted doesn't make sense; as if that `CASE` was supposed to be in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
select ...
from table_1 a, table_2 b, table_3 c
where a.column_id = case when b.status in ('AC', 'AB') then c.column_id
                         when b.status in ('GC') then 241
                    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the values which satisfy the dynamic condition.

You can use boolean operation instead of `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
FROM 
...
WHERE where ((a.column_id != 241 and a.column_id = c.column_id 
              and b.status in ('AC', 'AB'))
      OR (a.column_id = 241 and  b.status in ('GC') ))
```